# QML property bind

Tags: javascript, qml, qtquick2

When the context variable changes, does the isOn property is also modified within the code bellow?

```
property bool isOn: {
    if(context === undefined)
        return false;
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is, to try it out:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 500
    height: 800
    visible: true

    property bool isOn: {
        if(context === undefined)
            return false;
        return true
    }
    property var context
    Button {
        text: isOn
        onClicked: (context ? context = undefined  : context = 1)
    }
}
```

Hint: **yes**

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it